# AES Rijndael on PHP server and iOS generates sometimes different ciphers

Tags: php, ios, encryption, aes, rijndael

I'm using NSData+AESCrypt category by Jim Dovey and NSString+AESCrypt by Michael Sedlaczek (2011-02-22).

And on PHP I have a simple script:

```
<?php
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$key = '01234567890123456789012345678901';
$plaintext = "myworda";

$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$base64encoded_ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
echo "ciphertext: ".$base64encoded_ciphertext."<br/>";
?>
```

In ObjC:

```
NSString *key = @"01234567890123456789012345678901";
NSString *plaintext = [@"+l56Ia4yyK19D2x2+oCXuw==" AES256DecryptWithKey: key];
NSLog(@"plaintext: %@", plaintext);
```

I change the variable $plaintext in PHP, run script and copy and paste the output-cipher to the Objective-c to decrypt it.

And:

1. "myword" gives me "+l56Ia4yyK19D2x2+oCXuw==" and I decrypt in and get "myword" on iOS [OK]
2. "good morning" gives me "5UdImsV1pQs60ovXmH74HQ==" and I decrypt in and get "good morning" on iOS [OK]
3. "Schröder" gives me "KqNSCE8nGsYUYVdGZ2tnMw==" and I decrypt in and get "Schröder" on iOS [OK]
4. "Schröder" gives me "KqNSCE8nGsYUYVdGZ2tnMw==" and I decrypt in and get "Schröder" on iOS [OK]
5. "very long text" gives me "lsa+QF3IHQnAFiOjl2Heyg==" and I decrypt in and get "very long text" on iOS [OK]
6. "very very very very long text" gives me "kl/ThEyuyUMmKSqU4/fJSzzJOyvsXrGRt5/zsnqjQww=" and I cannot decrypt it on iOS [FAIL]

Why #5 fails? If I try to encrypt "very very very very long text" using Xcode, I get "kl/ThEyuyUMmKSqU4/fJS90UZoJ73S4gox2uCoWoIL8=" notice that:
kl/ThEyuyUMmKSqU4/fJS == kl/ThEyuyUMmKSqU4/fJS
zzJOyvsXrGRt5/zsnqjQww != 90UZoJ73S4gox2uCoWoIL8=

But going further, encrypting "good morning" on Xcode gives me "hVq1AuR8PAXSOztK26pmMw==", while PHP gave "5UdImsV1pQs60ovXmH74HQ==", but Xcode decrypts both to "good morning" using the same key.

Please help.

Comment: Review the information posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461419/aescrypt-decryption-between-ios-and-php-fixed

Answer (score 4):

Your PHP code is using ECB mode.  I cannot see where you are setting the mode in ObjC.  Presumably you are using its default mode.  It is possible that the ObjC default mode is not ECB, more likely CBC.  Also notice that whenever your plaintext is 16 bytes or less (that is one block or less) the decryption works.  When it is greater than 16 bytes (that is it extends into a second block) it fails.

I suspect that the ObjC default is CBC mode with a zero IV.  That will act as if it is ECB for the first block only, and differ for the second and subsequent blocks.

ECB mode is unsafe and leaks information.  Use CBC mode with a specified IV instead.  At the very least change your PHP code to use CBC mode instead of ECB mode.

Answer (score -3):

You encrypt the message using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` which gives you a block size of 128 bits, or 16 bytes.
You'll notice that `very very very very long text` is larger than 16 bytes.

So I'm guessing you're decryption on ios uses a different block size. I'm not familiar with ios, but `AES256DecryptWithKey` seems to indicate it uses a block size of 256 bits.

Try using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` in your PHP code, or change the ios code to use `AES128DecryptWithKey` (I don't know if that exist, again, I don't know ios)

Comment: The 256 refers to the key size (in bits) and not the block size, which is fixed at 128 bits (for key sizes of 128, 192, or 256 bits).