# How can I port this PHP line to Java?

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I have a problem with AES encryption and the customer showed me their PHP server code for "decrypting". Curiously enough the exact code has been taken from S.O. (not surprising). I found this out because the code the customer passed me had the exact same comment! :)

Anyway, it's a piece of PHP code taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461419/aescrypt-decryption-between-ios-and-php-fixed) S.O. question.

I am trying to do the same with Java but I don't know what this exact line is adding:

```
$key = 'a16byteslongkey!';

$padded_key = $key . str_repeat(chr(0x00), 16); // Argh!
```

(note the // Argh! comment was not mine ;)

Is it trying to add chr(0x00) to make a 32 bytes key (because the $key is 16?) if so, how would I do the same in Java?

Comment: @Josh perhaps I should have clarified: what is chr(0x00) doing in php?

Comment: In PHP, strings are binary-safe (every "character" in the string is in fact just a byte), but Java's `String` instances are not (they actually represent characters, not bytes). For binary encryption keys you probably shouldn't be using `String` objects but rather a `byte[]` or something like a `Key` class.

Comment: @AnotherCode Indeed, thanks for the clarification. Turns out the customer was doing a "hacky" thing on the server side, completing the 16 bytes key with 16 zeros so it adds 32… after padding the fixed key with 16 "zeros" it all worked. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gareth stated this returns the character with ASCII code 0. Using this we can make a function which repeats a string:

```
public static String strRepeat(String toRepeat, int reps){
    //Sanity checks go here!
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int x = 0; x < reps; x++){
        sb.append(toRepeat);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now the line can be replaced with:

```
String paddedKey = key + strRepeat('\0', 16); // Argh!
```

Answer (score 1):

`chr(0x00)` should return the character with the ASCII code `0` which I think can be represented by `'\0'` in Java.