# need a decrypt/encrypt basic algorithm for PHP AND iOS

Tags: php, ios, encryption

I am looking for a way to encrypt a string in iOS, send it to a PHP server and decrypt it there.
server would send a normal message back to iOS, no need to encrypt.
Any idea how to accomplish that ?

**EDIT:** The encryption should have a similar key hardcoded on both ends.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no ios experience, but I found something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461419/aescrypt-decryption-between-ios-and-php-fixed

Comment: Google OpenSSL, i'm sure you'll find implementations for iOS and PHP

Answer (score 0):

How about base64 encoding and decoding?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

and for iOS: [How to Base64 encoding on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882277/how-to-base64-encode-on-the-iphone)

Comment: I don't think base64 has a key related to the message?

Comment: I wrote this before your EDIT :) sorry

Comment: My apologies, your comment caused my edit. Sorry I guess I forgot to point that out.

Comment: but, you can do it with a key, but then we're adapting it: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2008/03/24/php-encrypt-decrypt-using-base64/ . as you can see, these 2 functions use a predefined key to do some more encrypting and decrypting